# App crashes on iPhone 5

Tags: objective-c, ios, amazon-web-services

I made an app that displays images from an AWS server. It's working fine for iPhone 4 and older but when I run my app on an iPhone 5 the app crashes when running using wifi or 3G connection. I did many tests that show me when I use S3GetObject...

```
3GetObjectResponse *getObjectResponse = [[AmazonClientManager s3] getObject:getObjectRequest];

UIImage *tampon = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:getObjectResponse.body];
```

The app crashes, I don't know if the AWS-SDK is compatible with iOS 6 or not, please help me.

Comment: And what does the crash log say?

Comment: there are no log because when i running the app connecting to mac that work fine but when i execute the app with connection wifi or 3g that crash = back in home screen of iphone

Comment: My first guess would be that your getObjectResponse is nil due to connectivity issue

Comment: No, any object can be sent any message when it is nil with no issue. The error lies elsewhere.

Comment: You do not know what is made with received object / properties.

Comment: @MedReda I help maintain the AWS SDK for iOS and both the iPhone 5 and iOS6 are supported with the latest versions.  It would be helpful if you could include the creation of the S3GetObjectRequest in your code snippet as how this is created can have effects on the response.

Additionally, you can get logs from the crashed app by connecting the device after and go to Xcode > Organizer > Devices > Your Device > Device Logs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on one of your [other questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13209022/understanding-crash-report), it appears you may still be including an older version of the AWS SDK for iOS which had problems with crashing when built for release because of the inclusion of the GTMLogger library.

Please make sure to remove any references to previous versions of the AWS SDK for iOS and also update your projects Framework include path.

You can confirm you are using the latest version of the SDK by logging the value returned from

```
[AmazonSDKUtil userAgentString]
```

Comment: thank you Bob kinney i found the solution in this forum https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=100271

Comment: its your solution :D => [AmazonLogger turnLoggingOff];

Comment: @MedReda I'm glad you were able to solve the immediate problem, but my answer regarding making sure you're using the latest version is still important.  Do make sure you are using the latest version of the SDK.

Comment: I find that: aws-sdk-iOS/1.3.0 iPhone-OS/5.1.1 fr_FR

Comment: aws-sdk-iOS/1.3.0 it's the last version ??

Comment: @MedReda The latest version is 1.4.3.  You can download it at https://aws.amazon.com/sdkforios/

Comment: Thank you very much Mister Bob Kinney :)

Comment: Hello Bob Kinney I have a question: i want do display video From aws S3 but i don't know to proceed

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you are using the AWS SDK with Grand Central Dispatch, and calling synchronous `getObject:` and updating UIs on the same thread. You need to make sure to call `getObject:` on a background thread, and update UIs on the main thread. Your code should look something like the following:

```
dispatch_async( dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{

    for(int i=0;i<ads.count;i++){

        NSString *phot =[ads objectAtIndex:i];
        NSLog(@"hna%@",phot);
        S3GetObjectRequest  *getObjectRequest  = [[S3GetObjectRequest alloc] initWithKey:phot   withBucket:@"olfactifPhoto"];
        S3GetObjectResponse *getObjectResponse = [[AmazonClientManager s3] getObject:getObjectRequest];

        dispatch_async( dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

            UIImage *tampon = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:getObjectResponse.body];
            UIImageView *tempImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:tampon];
            tempImageView.frame = CGRectMake(10,currentXLocation, 300, 310);

            NSLog(@" il est dans la position %f",tempImageView.frame.origin.y);
            self.monImage = tempImageView;

            [scroll addSubview:monImage];
        });
    }

});
```

Comment: it doesn't work i guess the speed of loading the image that crash in iPhone 5