# understanding crash report

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, amazon-s3, amazon-web-services

I have a crash app when i use S3getObjectRequest when i connect iPhone 5 to cable its work fine but when i disconnect the cable  to use my app with wifi the app crash here is the crash log :

```
Incident Identifier: BFD481E9-114E-4676-AA36-CC544663BA8C
CrashReporter Key:   8187acf23ebe01b6678e473e051986b72bd0febd
Hardware Model:      iPhone5,2
Process:         friendsCam [1513]
Path:            /var/mobile/Applications/90A9B2A4-906E-48D3-8357-   1E23FB8ACD76/friendsCam.app/friendsCam
Identifier:      friendsCam
Version:         ??? (???)
Code Type:       ARM (Native)
Parent Process:  launchd [1]

Date/Time:       2012-11-03 12:59:38.706 +0100
OS Version:      iOS 6.0.1 (10A525)
Report Version:  104

Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
Crashed Thread:  9

Last Exception Backtrace:
0   CoreFoundation                  0x3bd2b3e2 __exceptionPreprocess + 158
1   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x3ad8495e objc_exception_throw + 26
2   CoreFoundation                  0x3bd2b302 +[NSException raise:format:] + 102
3   Foundation                      0x346b518e _NSFileHandleRaiseOperationException + 150
4   Foundation                      0x346938ee -[NSConcreteFileHandle writeData:] + 126
5   friendsCam                      0x000fbeb4 -[NSFileHandle(GTMFileHandleLogWriter) logMessage:level:] (GTMLogger.m:315)
6   friendsCam                      0x000fbd9e -[GTMLogger(PrivateMethods) logInternalFunc:format:valist:level:] (GTMLogger.m:292)
7   friendsCam                      0x000fbb00 -[GTMLogger logDebug:] (GTMLogger.m:199)
8   friendsCam                      0x000f190e -[AmazonS3Client invoke:] (AmazonS3Client.m:368)
9   friendsCam                      0x000f1024 -[AmazonS3Client getObject:] (AmazonS3Client.m:137)
10  friendsCam                      0x000b49b8 -[Home loadingImage] (Home.m:142)
11  Foundation                      0x346f5a3c __NSThread__main__ + 968
12  libsystem_c.dylib               0x350100dc _pthread_start + 304
13  libsystem_c.dylib               0x3500ffa4 thread_start + 4


Thread 0 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
Thread 0:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x3ba84e30 mach_msg_trap + 20
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x3ba84fd0 mach_msg + 48
2   CoreFoundation                  0x3bd002b6 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 126
3   CoreFoundation                  0x3bcfefd6 __CFRunLoopRun + 814
4   CoreFoundation                  0x3bc72238 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 352
5   CoreFoundation                  0x3bc720c4 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 100
6   GraphicsServices                0x3bdce336 GSEventRunModal + 70
7   UIKit                           0x3558f28c UIApplicationMain + 1116
8   friendsCam                      0x0003bbd8 main (main.m:16)
9   friendsCam                      0x0003a104 start + 36

Thread 1 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.root.default-priority
Thread 1:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x3ba956a4 __semwait_signal + 24
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x350151be nanosleep + 138
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x35075e4e sleep + 42
3   friendsCam                      0x000b7618 __20-[Home loadingImage]_block_invoke_0 (Home.m:119)
4   libdispatch.dylib               0x34b13790 _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 8
5   libdispatch.dylib               0x34b17652 _dispatch_root_queue_drain + 274
6   libdispatch.dylib               0x34b177d4 _dispatch_worker_thread2 + 88
7   libsystem_c.dylib               0x350057ee _pthread_wqthread + 358
8   libsystem_c.dylib               0x35005680 start_wqthread + 4

Thread 2 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.libdispatch-manager
Thread 2:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x3ba855d0 kevent64 + 24
1   libdispatch.dylib               0x34b18d22 _dispatch_mgr_invoke + 806
2   libdispatch.dylib               0x34b14374 _dispatch_mgr_thread + 32

Thread 3:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x3ba95d98 __workq_kernreturn + 8
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x35005ad6 _pthread_workq_return + 14
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x350057f2 _pthread_wqthread + 362
3   libsystem_c.dylib               0x35005680 start_wqthread + 4

Thread 4 name:  WebThread
Thread 4:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x3ba84e30 mach_msg_trap + 20
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x3ba84fd0 mach_msg + 48
2   CoreFoundation                  0x3bd002b6 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 126
3   CoreFoundation                  0x3bcff02c __CFRunLoopRun + 900
4   CoreFoundation                  0x3bc72238 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 352
5   CoreFoundation                  0x3bc720c4 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 100
6   WebCore                         0x36b12a58 _ZL12RunWebThreadPv + 440
7   libsystem_c.dylib               0x350100de _pthread_start + 306
8   libsystem_c.dylib               0x3500ffa4 thread_start + 4

Thread 5 name:  com.apple.NSURLConnectionLoader
Thread 5:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x3ba84e30 mach_msg_trap + 20
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x3ba84fd0 mach_msg + 48
2   CoreFoundation                  0x3bd002b6 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 126
3   CoreFoundation                  0x3bcff02c __CFRunLoopRun + 900
4   CoreFoundation                  0x3bc72238 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 352
5   CoreFoundation                  0x3bc720c4 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 100
6   Foundation                      0x34672098 +[NSURLConnection(Loader) _resourceLoadLoop:] + 304
7   Foundation                      0x346f5a3c __NSThread__main__ + 968
8   libsystem_c.dylib               0x350100de _pthread_start + 306
9   libsystem_c.dylib               0x3500ffa4 thread_start + 4

Thread 6:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x3ba95d98 __workq_kernreturn + 8
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x35005ad6 _pthread_workq_return + 14
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x350057f2 _pthread_wqthread + 362
3   libsystem_c.dylib               0x35005680 start_wqthread + 4

Thread 7:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x3ba95d98 __workq_kernreturn + 8
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x35005ad6 _pthread_workq_return + 14
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x350057f2 _pthread_wqthread + 362
3   libsystem_c.dylib               0x35005680 start_wqthread + 4

Thread 8 name:  com.apple.CFSocket.private
Thread 8:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x3ba95594 __select + 20
1   CoreFoundation                  0x3bd04474 __CFSocketManager + 676
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x350100de _pthread_start + 306
3   libsystem_c.dylib               0x3500ffa4 thread_start + 4

Thread 9 Crashed:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x3ba95350 __pthread_kill + 8
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x3502dfb2 pthread_kill + 54
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x3506a366 abort + 90
3   libc++abi.dylib                 0x35125dda abort_message + 70
4   libc++abi.dylib                 0x35123094 _ZL17default_terminatev + 20
5   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x3ad84a58 _ZL15_objc_terminatev + 144
6   libc++abi.dylib                 0x35123118 _ZL19safe_handler_callerPFvvE + 76
7   libc++abi.dylib                 0x351231b0 std::terminate() + 16
8   libc++abi.dylib                 0x3512459a __cxa_throw + 118
9   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x3ad8499e objc_exception_throw + 90
10  CoreFoundation                  0x3bd2b302 +[NSException raise:format:] + 102
11  Foundation                      0x346b518e _NSFileHandleRaiseOperationException + 150
12  Foundation                      0x346938ee -[NSConcreteFileHandle writeData:] + 126
13  friendsCam                      0x000fbeb4 -[NSFileHandle(GTMFileHandleLogWriter) logMessage:level:] (GTMLogger.m:315)
14  friendsCam                      0x000fbd9e -[GTMLogger(PrivateMethods) logInternalFunc:format:valist:level:] (GTMLogger.m:292)
15  friendsCam                      0x000fbb00 -[GTMLogger logDebug:] (GTMLogger.m:199)
16  friendsCam                      0x000f190e -[AmazonS3Client invoke:] (AmazonS3Client.m:368)
17  friendsCam                      0x000f1024 -[AmazonS3Client getObject:] (AmazonS3Client.m:137)
18  friendsCam                      0x000b49b8 -[Home loadingImage] (Home.m:142)
19  Foundation                      0x346f5a3c __NSThread__main__ + 968
20  libsystem_c.dylib               0x350100de _pthread_start + 306
21  libsystem_c.dylib               0x3500ffa4 thread_start + 4

Thread 9 crashed with ARM Thread State (32-bit):
    r0: 0x00000000    r1: 0x00000000      r2: 0x00000000      r3: 0x3cd22524
    r4: 0x00000006    r5: 0x05ce9000      r6: 0x1f0bc854      r7: 0x05ce8344
    r8: 0x1f0bc830    r9: 0x00000300     r10: 0x1f09d770     r11: 0x00000004
    ip: 0x00000148    sp: 0x05ce8338      lr: 0x3502dfb7      pc: 0x3ba95350
  cpsr: 0x00000010
```

can any one help me to fix it

Answer (score 4):

in the console report you have

```
Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
```

This means you are using some thing which is deallocated.

Here are some tutorials how to debug the code when any crash occur, by raywenderlich.

[My App Crashed – Now What? 1/2](http://www.raywenderlich.com/10209/my-app-crashed-now-what-part-1)

[My App Crashed – Now What? 2/2](http://www.raywenderlich.com/10505/my-app-crashed-now-what-part-2)