# How do I read an Xcode crash report?

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, symbolicatecrash

I have an app that I just submitted it to the app sore (The app was developed for me as I do not know iOS development I do however know know other coding languages). Apple rejected the app saying that is crashed (The strange thing is is never crashed in all tests I did, probably about 50!) I got their crash log, Symbolicated it in Xcode and get this as a result. The only problem is that I don't understand this either. 
I was wondering if someone can explain what this means, Where abouts in my code that this error is and how I can fix it.

```
Incident Identifier: 0E0825D2-FBE9-4BF1-8C7F-B83709C2991A
CrashReporter Key:   5b0d1e3117951cb6f669414656a30ad10c807e15
Hardware Model:      iPhone4,1
Process:         Chapter3 Framework [6333]
Path:            /var/mobile/Applications/4A4C7A70-1B6C-403E-8A98-6563BDF3AF83/Chapter3 Framework.app/Chapter3 Framework
Identifier:      Chapter3 Framework
Version:         ??? (???)
Code Type:       ARM (Native)
Parent Process:  launchd [1]

Date/Time:       2012-01-07 17:46:13.980 +1100
OS Version:      iPhone OS 5.0.1 (9A405)
Report Version:  104

Exception Type:  EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV)
Exception Codes: KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0xb0000008
Crashed Thread:  0

Thread 0 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
Thread 0 Crashed:
0   libobjc.A.dylib                0x31be9fbc objc_msgSend + 16
1   Chapter3 Framework             0x00004d78 0x1000 + 15736
2   Chapter3 Framework             0x000028b2 0x1000 + 6322
3   UIKit                          0x35531e5e -[UIApplication _handleApplicationSuspend:eventInfo:] + 754
4   UIKit                          0x354c1d10 -[UIApplication handleEvent:withNewEvent:] + 2024
5   UIKit                          0x354c13b8 -[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 48
6   UIKit                          0x354c0d26 _UIApplicationHandleEvent + 5802
7   GraphicsServices               0x37bdedec PurpleEventCallback + 876
8   CoreFoundation                 0x380dd54c __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE1_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 32
9   CoreFoundation                 0x380dd4ee __CFRunLoopDoSource1 + 134
10  CoreFoundation                 0x380dc33c __CFRunLoopRun + 1364
11  CoreFoundation                 0x3805f4d6 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 294
12  CoreFoundation                 0x3805f39e CFRunLoopRunInMode + 98
13  GraphicsServices               0x37bddfc6 GSEventRunModal + 150
14  UIKit                          0x354ef73c UIApplicationMain + 1084
15  Chapter3 Framework             0x000024d6 0x1000 + 5334
16  Chapter3 Framework             0x0000246c 0x1000 + 5228

Thread 1 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.libdispatch-manager
Thread 1:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x339933b4 kevent + 24
1   libdispatch.dylib              0x37dc7f74 _dispatch_mgr_invoke + 708
2   libdispatch.dylib              0x37dc7c92 _dispatch_mgr_thread + 30

Thread 2 name:  WebThread
Thread 2:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x33993010 mach_msg_trap + 20
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x33993206 mach_msg + 50
2   CoreFoundation                 0x380dd41c __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 120
3   CoreFoundation                 0x380dc154 __CFRunLoopRun + 876
4   CoreFoundation                 0x3805f4d6 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 294
5   CoreFoundation                 0x3805f39e CFRunLoopRunInMode + 98
6   WebCore                        0x32930128 _ZL12RunWebThreadPv + 396
7   libsystem_c.dylib              0x36531c16 _pthread_start + 314
8   libsystem_c.dylib              0x36531ad0 thread_start + 0

Thread 3:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x339a3cd4 __workq_kernreturn + 8
1   libsystem_c.dylib              0x3652c30a _pthread_wqthread + 610
2   libsystem_c.dylib              0x3652c09c start_wqthread + 0

Thread 0 crashed with ARM Thread State:
    r0: 0x001562b0    r1: 0x30b6f09c      r2: 0x00000001      r3: 0x00000014
    r4: 0xb0000000    r5: 0x00352ea0      r6: 0x3f398608      r7: 0x2fdfe760
    r8: 0x0034fa00    r9: 0x0c2dbc27     r10: 0x00113560     r11: 0x3f38d010
    ip: 0x0001924c    sp: 0x2fdfe750      lr: 0x00004d7f      pc: 0x31be9fbc
  cpsr: 0x200f0030

Binary Images:
    0x1000 -    0x18fff +Chapter3 Framework armv7  <deb18410d000314fac23e4c6b05a8265> /var/mobile/Applications/4A4C7A70-1B6C-403E-8A98-6563BDF3AF83/Chapter3 Framework.app/Chapter3 Framework
0x2fecf000 - 0x2fef0fff  dyld armv7  <be7c0b491a943054ad12eb5060f1da06> /usr/lib/dyld
0x30c2d000 - 0x30c30fff  libsystem_network.dylib armv7  <b18e0a845b1e317c8abcf6b5d06b29a0> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_network.dylib
0x30c9e000 - 0x30ca4fff  MobileIcons armv7  <2f4c13053206306996726629b0b7eb01> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileIcons.framework/MobileIcons
0x30cb8000 - 0x30cc4fff  CoreVideo armv7  <474c89eb09fe3464851a20d76052341b> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreVideo.framework/CoreVideo
0x30f5e000 - 0x30fa7fff  AddressBook armv7  <0a858565acd03f28a1bc69a650b64a7b> /System/Library/Frameworks/AddressBook.framework/AddressBook
0x30faf000 - 0x30ff4fff  GeoServices armv7  <6c9eb6372f723a57852cfc9ed7b78e31> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/GeoServices.framework/GeoServices
0x31194000 - 0x3119efff  libvMisc.dylib armv7  <b93ee3136d1c3d44b1e513a56bb0f86c> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libvMisc.dylib
0x31543000 - 0x31543fff  libCVMSPluginSupport.dylib armv7  <85582e1094633fccb52b50ca13c5a5d0> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/libCVMSPluginSupport.dylib
0x316e3000 - 0x316e4fff  DataMigration armv7  <d067b65a904a3f438b5d9e13b208b117> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DataMigration.framework/DataMigration
0x317e1000 - 0x317e2fff  CoreSurface armv7  <fcb6a869daef3a3abc4300c28b218e9f> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CoreSurface.framework/CoreSurface
0x317e3000 - 0x317e4fff  libremovefile.dylib armv7  <9c8cee9652453241ac1fc99eab05c40a> /usr/lib/system/libremovefile.dylib
0x319b2000 - 0x319bafff  MobileWiFi armv7  <f07cb8d6dadf36919bae8ef6e5ce1749> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileWiFi.framework/MobileWiFi
0x31be6000 - 0x31cacfff  libobjc.A.dylib armv7  <ebbb32df194b331e9b3dc14e40f46833> /usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib
0x31d24000 - 0x31d5bfff  Security armv7  <b89c9f6373f037f2a4801558f97b9a95> /System/Library/Frameworks/Security.framework/Security
0x31d75000 - 0x31d79fff  libGFXShared.dylib armv7  <0a36fb9d60a43479943bafb2f81313b1> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/libGFXShared.dylib
0x31d9b000 - 0x31d9dfff  MobileInstallation armv7  <4ccf76f0e6cb3cd7b4e0087c2f284a1d> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileInstallation.framework/MobileInstallation
0x31db0000 - 0x31ef5fff  CoreGraphics armv7  <641fb6e558f239588a8bd05dbefff99a> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreGraphics.framework/CoreGraphics
0x31f46000 - 0x31f49fff  libcompiler_rt.dylib armv7  <414332f9a55238bab2cbec323e0fc8da> /usr/lib/system/libcompiler_rt.dylib
0x31f9f000 - 0x3211dfff  Foundation armv7  <ce466f428d953caaac6641d186665809> /System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Foundation
0x3214e000 - 0x32198fff  libvDSP.dylib armv7  <d8489a4ce77933abac52394c43ff5513> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libvDSP.dylib
0x32199000 - 0x32199fff  libunwind.dylib armv7  <d21222aad8c93d6c9580f9bf47071946> /usr/lib/system/libunwind.dylib
0x321ad000 - 0x321f7fff  CoreTelephony armv7  <1f4cacb552533c948122cb180f4192b3> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreTelephony.framework/CoreTelephony
0x32203000 - 0x322d3fff  WebKit armv7  <74661b1bf4613aafb827bfe0134ed92b> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/WebKit.framework/WebKit
0x323a9000 - 0x323ccfff  PrintKit armv7  <279fb51deec3377ab9f820af2da4d915> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/PrintKit.framework/PrintKit
0x323f7000 - 0x323fdfff  liblaunch.dylib armv7  <09f21c3e774c30b1aab1b56c2d6efbc3> /usr/lib/system/liblaunch.dylib
0x323fe000 - 0x32400fff  libCoreVMClient.dylib armv7  <6ddb7cf8a93830628787a5b83eea0f1d> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/libCoreVMClient.dylib
0x32408000 - 0x324cefff  GLEngine armv7  <0231a8c1fa3f3cfe82e83fc53c0cf5d8> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/GLEngine.bundle/GLEngine
0x32595000 - 0x32596fff  libdnsinfo.dylib armv7  <dbd1e77a4beb309d8f160d927d442467> /usr/lib/system/libdnsinfo.dylib
0x32627000 - 0x3262cfff  libcopyfile.dylib armv7  <9072462f28af3665875b3ecaba002c00> /usr/lib/system/libcopyfile.dylib
0x32888000 - 0x3303ffff  WebCore armv7  <7137e0ea008f3a3e8ae9e57f96d34d1d> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/WebCore.framework/WebCore
0x33045000 - 0x3304ffff  libbz2.1.0.dylib armv7  <28583efb9f1b38e7ae83c667b07dbd08> /usr/lib/libbz2.1.0.dylib
0x330cb000 - 0x330d8fff  libbsm.0.dylib armv7  <a6414b0a5fd53df58c4f0b2f8878f81f> /usr/lib/libbsm.0.dylib
0x33371000 - 0x3341bfff  libBLAS.dylib armv7  <9aabff01422f3cb8960f93d11d2b6de1> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libBLAS.dylib
0x334c5000 - 0x334defff  OpenAL armv7  <87e810d1a1e93b5b8523a4f97fdaaec5> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenAL.framework/OpenAL
0x334df000 - 0x334e6fff  AssetsLibraryServices armv7  <c0093954f6ee329aa6b4848215bcb8c0> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AssetsLibraryServices.framework/AssetsLibraryServices
0x334e7000 - 0x334eafff  libmacho.dylib armv7  <3237bc9c109e3354bc4b38b957243f31> /usr/lib/system/libmacho.dylib
0x334eb000 - 0x33501fff  EAP8021X armv7  <16801802d86e3c479f3034034192faed> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/EAP8021X.framework/EAP8021X
0x33519000 - 0x3352dfff  PersistentConnection armv7  <81eb1b3e08cf3d7196313307ad60649d> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/PersistentConnection.framework/PersistentConnection
0x3352e000 - 0x33534fff  MobileKeyBag armv7  <f5633749a1c83058a28cd7d0b488e19f> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileKeyBag.framework/MobileKeyBag
0x335a9000 - 0x335a9fff  liblangid.dylib armv7  <342170169bf232a0888912f5ef97112d> /usr/lib/liblangid.dylib
0x335c8000 - 0x336ecfff  JavaScriptCore armv7  <24ff2747b3973aecb9c37960eba5ff4d> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/JavaScriptCore.framework/JavaScriptCore
0x3375d000 - 0x33768fff  AccountSettings armv7  <090bb6a4f97433089b5cabc6a40c619a> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AccountSettings.framework/AccountSettings
0x33769000 - 0x337a5fff  AppSupport armv7  <de0c2fbb95f8383db43acfb44e9c66fe> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AppSupport.framework/AppSupport
0x337ec000 - 0x3382ffff  libcommonCrypto.dylib armv7  <be9a231cfe6e3ae387abb444a098bce9> /usr/lib/system/libcommonCrypto.dylib
0x33859000 - 0x33949fff  QuartzCore armv7  <ff595b1a042933249466e92433e1af6f> /System/Library/Frameworks/QuartzCore.framework/QuartzCore
0x33992000 - 0x339a8fff  libsystem_kernel.dylib armv7  <afd3cb06e20336dca2e5a6e11d080504> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_kernel.dylib
0x339a9000 - 0x33aaffff  IMGSGX543GLDriver armv7  <f92d0f00c6eb3fbdae116fb1febe4fb1> /System/Library/Extensions/IMGSGX543GLDriver.bundle/IMGSGX543GLDriver
0x33ab1000 - 0x33b08fff  CoreAudio armv7  <2e4975a2156e328585f2a478e80704fc> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreAudio.framework/CoreAudio
0x34203000 - 0x34228fff  OpenCL armv7  <e1d5bfcdb59934b0923b9307c75e7457> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/OpenCL.framework/OpenCL
0x34229000 - 0x3476dfff  FaceCoreLight armv7  <cc2edb3645d2390dbca5471d35f1bf6e> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/FaceCoreLight.framework/FaceCoreLight
0x34963000 - 0x34986fff  Bom armv7  <0e6087f75a81345ea81751197ccb712c> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Bom.framework/Bom
0x34988000 - 0x3499dfff  libresolv.9.dylib armv7  <97d6ebbb53ae3e0480f51771c9665613> /usr/lib/libresolv.9.dylib
0x34aa1000 - 0x34ab0fff  GenerationalStorage armv7  <c581bffc87013530b3c2d017142395e6> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/GenerationalStorage.framework/GenerationalStorage
0x34ab1000 - 0x34c6dfff  ImageIO armv7  <df300f66a317352e92354a8a48af3453> /System/Library/Frameworks/ImageIO.framework/ImageIO
0x34ce9000 - 0x34d32fff  libc++.1.dylib armv7  <ad15503487243836b7c296f3439ba0c1> /usr/lib/libc++.1.dylib
0x34d93000 - 0x34d94fff  libsystem_blocks.dylib armv7  <4bb9797771d037879bec814fe750d86d> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_blocks.dylib
0x35131000 - 0x35135fff  libAccessibility.dylib armv7  <ee734c0e964934a887a66d170270b114> /usr/lib/libAccessibility.dylib
0x351ac000 - 0x351c5fff  libRIP.A.dylib armv7  <ad22ea5ee99a358691f9820e62c85058> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreGraphics.framework/Resources/libRIP.A.dylib
0x351c6000 - 0x351c6fff  libkeymgr.dylib armv7  <791bb8b832943b2392c0c35228f52e09> /usr/lib/system/libkeymgr.dylib
0x351f5000 - 0x35214fff  libSystem.B.dylib armv7  <31a0ffbb18bf3a28b46fd286733e7d9f> /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib
0x35263000 - 0x3526ffff  libCRFSuite.dylib armv7  <ea460e3f1ac338a9885d5752864dbffb> /usr/lib/libCRFSuite.dylib
0x35270000 - 0x3535efff  libiconv.2.dylib armv7  <6e858938edb93162ba8cf25702f08b16> /usr/lib/libiconv.2.dylib
0x3548a000 - 0x3548efff  libcache.dylib armv7  <4511f0ec5b713636aaade7245a12553c> /usr/lib/system/libcache.dylib
0x354be000 - 0x35957fff  UIKit armv7  <97b527cd6fba35c6bb39263e0f362223> /System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/UIKit
0x35995000 - 0x3599efff  libMobileGestalt.dylib armv7  <bf8d7c30f11a393a8adf4c8277e65aa3> /usr/lib/libMobileGestalt.dylib
0x35af5000 - 0x35b40fff  CoreLocation armv7  <e959d4dd596b31eeaa49c8c0156b1e12> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreLocation.framework/CoreLocation
0x35c20000 - 0x35c20fff  vecLib armv7  <106ef8294b0d3c2d89e9230527846227> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/vecLib
0x35c21000 - 0x35ee2fff  libLAPACK.dylib armv7  <5490a87fe5153771b9c67940292842ba> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libLAPACK.dylib
0x35ee3000 - 0x35ee4fff  libdyld.dylib armv7  <f1963e7ef64e39a58ec1e39ed7c74849> /usr/lib/system/libdyld.dylib
0x35f2b000 - 0x35f2cfff  libsystem_sandbox.dylib armv7  <b8612b4ce18535aaa94f4b75c730e090> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_sandbox.dylib
0x35f44000 - 0x35f49fff  libsystem_dnssd.dylib armv7  <4d8b38f1cb603f0d8af78c56c485f05a> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_dnssd.dylib
0x35f4a000 - 0x35f7ffff  SystemConfiguration armv7  <753be0ebdcb13b24b1a4adcdc94d6bd9> /System/Library/Frameworks/SystemConfiguration.framework/SystemConfiguration
0x36326000 - 0x36329fff  CoreTime armv7  <e2f02260f2a63359b9a0a47c69f59c9e> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CoreTime.framework/CoreTime
0x36522000 - 0x365affff  libsystem_c.dylib armv7  <1707c3cf3c5b3045af4bed38ff8420a6> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_c.dylib
0x365df000 - 0x367bcfff  AudioToolbox armv7  <da4f78fd20fb3b42b1a8be4f383d9c12> /System/Library/Frameworks/AudioToolbox.framework/AudioToolbox
0x367c2000 - 0x36841fff  libsqlite3.dylib armv7  <af4718fee01734748c42f2214ab6883d> /usr/lib/libsqlite3.dylib
0x36a3d000 - 0x36a5dfff  libxslt.1.dylib armv7  <f37418b7e89137bba433677d61cd779d> /usr/lib/libxslt.1.dylib
0x36a5e000 - 0x36b0bfff  libxml2.2.dylib armv7  <78462273eb5b38d1a0873b02f0e35e23> /usr/lib/libxml2.2.dylib
0x36b0c000 - 0x36b1bfff  OpenGLES armv7  <6d1afb451f50310895ec59864739e781> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/OpenGLES
0x36b68000 - 0x36b6dfff  libGPUSupportMercury.dylib armv7  <2066fe9b4ee73d1d83f5801b6d0bb432> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/GPUSupport.framework/libGPUSupportMercury.dylib
0x36b72000 - 0x36c41fff  libGLProgrammability.dylib armv7  <cb91cd9952e7371a9659da26034c8324> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/libGLProgrammability.dylib
0x36c86000 - 0x36dcffff  libicucore.A.dylib armv7  <1bc960f75d633190a09b093209a9f0c5> /usr/lib/libicucore.A.dylib
0x36e6b000 - 0x36e7afff  SpringBoardServices armv7  <79f1564c1b23303eb3b7db67f9375228> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/SpringBoardServices.framework/SpringBoardServices
0x36edf000 - 0x36ee2fff  CaptiveNetwork armv7  <c3a5b1659eb0302eb205498ffacb09f1> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CaptiveNetwork.framework/CaptiveNetwork
0x36ee3000 - 0x36f23fff  libGLImage.dylib armv7  <9440420d838a382caa175399d74a5044> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/libGLImage.dylib
0x36f24000 - 0x36f3afff  libmis.dylib armv7  <fd046316dedc34dd81a6601ea3b1e8a6> /usr/lib/libmis.dylib
0x36f3b000 - 0x36f84fff  ManagedConfiguration armv7  <05711081dd883c58a844c5f9c251e8c9> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ManagedConfiguration.framework/ManagedConfiguration
0x36fa9000 - 0x36fa9fff  libgcc_s.1.dylib armv7  <69d8dab7388b33d38b30708fd6b6a340> /usr/lib/libgcc_s.1.dylib
0x37023000 - 0x37034fff  libxpc.dylib armv7  <7d49e385ee5d3e7eb08d06525abd6435> /usr/lib/system/libxpc.dylib
0x3703a000 - 0x37073fff  VideoToolbox armv7  <49f9f09f23f7396b94a29bb1280759fe> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/VideoToolbox.framework/VideoToolbox
0x370a3000 - 0x370b4fff  DataAccessExpress armv7  <6bc443b0f87e338698cac9e5a96e8f8f> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DataAccessExpress.framework/DataAccessExpress
0x372cf000 - 0x372d6fff  ProtocolBuffer armv7  <6ca7dca9370132a2a592356bf9f2170b> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ProtocolBuffer.framework/ProtocolBuffer
0x37317000 - 0x37368fff  libstdc++.6.dylib armv7  <dc2061145c1a3307829d4f3bfc547c1a> /usr/lib/libstdc++.6.dylib
0x37369000 - 0x37375fff  libz.1.dylib armv7  <eef915ed9b2c3433b03fd9030957b945> /usr/lib/libz.1.dylib
0x37456000 - 0x3745cfff  liblockdown.dylib armv7  <bfaf7fb16e5a3b2ea07c47b8b2f2b64e> /usr/lib/liblockdown.dylib
0x3755a000 - 0x375d3fff  ProofReader armv7  <09d057676f6837cd9e7a735444b67e77> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ProofReader.framework/ProofReader
0x375db000 - 0x376b2fff  CFNetwork armv7  <6fbc9f187eaa30009780e70288c9f289> /System/Library/Frameworks/CFNetwork.framework/CFNetwork
0x3770d000 - 0x3770dfff  Accelerate armv7  <a62771c826753815a5cae96eaa60ffd7> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Accelerate
0x37876000 - 0x3787afff  IOMobileFramebuffer armv7  <c2e6bd6dafde3097b47bc255a8c871ef> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IOMobileFramebuffer.framework/IOMobileFramebuffer
0x3787b000 - 0x378b6fff  libCGFreetype.A.dylib armv7  <753daf497ca736739a30126661a522f1> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreGraphics.framework/Resources/libCGFreetype.A.dylib
0x378b7000 - 0x378fbfff  MobileCoreServices armv7  <9a79a2d389ba35389a30782ed01c46dd> /System/Library/Frameworks/MobileCoreServices.framework/MobileCoreServices
0x378fc000 - 0x37900fff  IOSurface armv7  <0f003f50b18e3dbf87607d819e0ac6b9> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IOSurface.framework/IOSurface
0x37aa6000 - 0x37ae3fff  IOKit armv7  <e5f727892ee034a4be04e6da608f413f> /System/Library/Frameworks/IOKit.framework/Versions/A/IOKit
0x37b5a000 - 0x37b70fff  DictionaryServices armv7  <5bbab664f97932a79a1566fda3a4383e> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DictionaryServices.framework/DictionaryServices
0x37bda000 - 0x37be5fff  GraphicsServices armv7  <4ec745ffb2e039faab4b39a30268f707> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/GraphicsServices.framework/GraphicsServices
0x37bf4000 - 0x37c11fff  libsystem_info.dylib armv7  <1e36ab94661c372bab5a801d68c79353> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_info.dylib
0x37dc4000 - 0x37ddafff  libdispatch.dylib armv7  <defe319d1f4d3c1c8c4f18ebd96b396a> /usr/lib/system/libdispatch.dylib
0x37dfa000 - 0x37e43fff  CoreMedia armv7  <d585cf4e0cfa34fa8beaa43b06a4bcd7> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreMedia.framework/CoreMedia
0x37e46000 - 0x37e48fff  libCoreFSCache.dylib armv7  <1ece4be587ca397b8f0494c56ed46976> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/libCoreFSCache.dylib
0x37e51000 - 0x37e57fff  libnotify.dylib armv7  <1e374857ac68370095ddbafe94f021a1> /usr/lib/system/libnotify.dylib
0x37ec2000 - 0x37f9cfff  vImage armv7  <42a5e58ff1b9350cad90de36bd3ceb09> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vImage.framework/vImage
0x37f9f000 - 0x37fa3fff  AggregateDictionary armv7  <cfd957904957310381369729bfd9b2b0> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AggregateDictionary.framework/AggregateDictionary
0x37fa9000 - 0x38019fff  CoreImage armv7  <b1d0678497f43769840f173c0f9dce20> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreImage.framework/CoreImage
0x38048000 - 0x3804ffff  libc++abi.dylib armv7  <f769ce305c3033ee90e8c2ecc4846619> /usr/lib/libc++abi.dylib
0x38050000 - 0x38167fff  CoreFoundation armv7  <de9eefc6109735369cfd8f3de9895da0> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/CoreFoundation
0x3835d000 - 0x383aefff  CoreText armv7  <23150093d39b393e9bc5f8230176df47> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreText.framework/CoreText
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This kind of question have been asked many more times. Look at the below question.

[understanding crash report](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13209022/understanding-crash-report/13210038#13210038)

in the console report you have

```
Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
```

This means you are using some thing which is deallocated.

Here are some tutorials how to debug the code when any crash occur, by raywenderlich.

[My App Crashed – Now What? 1/2](http://www.raywenderlich.com/10209/my-app-crashed-now-what-part-1)

[My App Crashed – Now What? 2/2](http://www.raywenderlich.com/10505/my-app-crashed-now-what-part-2)

Answer (score 2):

You say you symbolicated it in Xcode, but I see unresolved addresses in frames 1, 2, 15, and 16 of the stack trace, in code loaded from something called “Chapter3 Framework”, which must be part of your app since it's not an Apple framework.  You need to get the `.dSYM` file for the version of “Chapter3 Framework” in your app.

Frame 3 of the stack trace is in `-[UIApplication _handleApplicationSuspend:eventInfo:]` and frame 2 is in some function in “Chapter3 Framework”.  The tester at Apple probably switched away from your app, which puts it in the background.  When an app enters the background, it sends the message `applicationDidEnterBackground:` to the app delegate.  So I guess frame 2 is in your app delegate's `applicationDidEnterBackground:` method.  Did you test switching away from your app?  Did you test switching away from it lots of times, with your app in different states?

The crash report says it crashed on iOS 5.0.1.  Did you test switching away from your app on iOS 5.0.1?

The crash report says it crashed on an “iPhone4,1”, which is an iPhone 4S.  Did you test switching away from your app on an iPhone 4S?

Did you test switching away from your app on iOS 5.0.1 on an iPhone 4S?

Did you test switching away from your app on a clean install of your app on iOS 5.0.1 on an iPhone 4S?

Comment: I am confused. I did all that apple said and symbolicated the crash report the other day. I just copied and pasted it today but it is different that it was the other day. I only noticed after i posted this question. I remember it was mentioning things like Facebook (my app requires you to log in with facebok, that is where it moves away from the app) in the crash report but now there is nothing. do you know why this could happen? I have tried clicking Re-symbolicate and importing it again but it doesn't seem to be symbolicating anymore.

Comment: Occam's Razor suggests you were looking at a different crash report the other day than the one you pasted in your post.

Answer (score 0):

```
15  Chapter3 Framework             0x000024d6 0x1000 + 5334
16  Chapter3 Framework             0x0000246c 0x1000 + 5228
```

You don't seem to have the symbols in a place where Xcode (Spotlight) can find it. You need the .app and .dsym files for the binary this crashlog is from.

```
Identifier:      Chapter3 Framework
Version:         ??? (???)
```

This looks like there's no version number available.